# iPhone Peer-to-Peer Connectivity Support in Titanium

Tags: iphone, p2p, titanium

Is it possible to implement [peer-to-peer connectivity](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3621) with Titanium Mobile for the iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course! You can use the Bonjour service and browser to host and connect to another user in your vicinity or local network. You could also do peer-to-peer over the internet by connecting to your own, centralized server using the HTTPClient or TCPSocket to stream data to various clients.

[Take a look at the Network module, which houses all of these objects.](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Network-module)

Answer (score 0):

As an update to this post and to add to Dawson's answer from several years ago now, there is a recently released Multipeer Module for iOS in Titanium available here https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/8294